# Does sizeof() show C++ class overhead?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test {
    int a;
public:
    int getA() {
        return a;
    }

Test(): a(1){}
Test(int i): a(i){}

};



int main() {
    Test t1(100);
    cout << sizeof(t1) << " " << sizeof(1) << endl; // 4 4
    return 0;
}
```

It seems that classes in c++ have no overhead at all. t1 is of size 4 like an integer. If I add another int member to Test, it will increase its size to 8.

I would have expected something that is bigger than 4

Is it true that classes have no overhead?

Comment: What's actually the question here?

Comment: no overhead thats pretty awesome

Comment: Why would it have any overhead? In doesn't have any virtual functions or virtual inheritance.

Comment: In general, the very concept of a class doesn't exist at runtime.

Comment: If you simply add a virtual function the game is changed

Comment: Try making a class with no data at all. It will have a size of 1. This is one way to produce overhead. Other is virtual inheritance or virtual functions

Comment: Re: "It seems that classes in c++ have no overhead at all." Indeed. C++ isn't Java. The underlying philosophy is if you don't use it you don't pay for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It seems that classes in c++ have no overhead at all.

As long as a class doesn't have virtual functions, then, yes. What kind of overhead do you expect? A virtual-less class is merely a collection of variables, with a set of functions associated with the type.

```
class Foo {
    int a;
    int bar() const { return a*a; }
};
```

could be trivially replaced by

```
struct Foo {
    int a;
}

int Foo_bar(Foo const *that) {
    return (that->a) * (that->a);
}
```

If you compiled each of those snippets, you'd see, that the assembly code looks almost identitcal.

---

However if you add one single virtual function, the game changes dramatically.

Comment: Or a parent class (not necessarily with virtual functions). Anything that would cause the class in question need to have reference to another object (e.g. a vtable).

Comment: @peterph: If the parent class does not have virtual functions, the increase in size was just the same as if you added a variable of the type of the parent class/struct at the top of the trivial-rewrite structure.

Comment: Although your answer is correct in the narrow case. Overhead is being narrowly defined here.

Answer (score 4):

There is overhead involved if you use `virtual` methods or `virtual` inheritance.

```
class foo {
public:
    virtual void bar() { }
    int i;
}
```

takes 8 bytes per instance on 32 bit systems, 4 for the vtable pointer, and 4 for the `int`.

Answer (score 4):

In C++ an object cannot have zero size. That is why most compilers insert a single redundant byte into instances of classes with no data. However, if you inherit from such a class and include data, compilers can optimize the one byte away.

```
#include <iostream>

class Empty
{
};

class Derived : public Empty
{
    int data_;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Empty empty;
    Derived derived;
    int x;
    std::cout << sizeof(empty) << std::endl;    // 1
    std::cout << sizeof(derived) << std::endl;  // 4
    std::cout << sizeof(x) << std::endl;        // 4

    return 0;
}
```

This was done on gcc 4.6.3 and it is called the "Empty base optimization". There are much less subtle ways to have both data and performance overhead. Virtual functions are the most important one in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

There are some overhead, for example below sample tells something:

```
class Test {
    char a;
public:
    virtual int getA() {
        return a;
    }    

Test(): a('a'){}
Test(char i): a(i){}
};
```

1. add virtual function to the class will add a pointer(vptr) size to class size.
2. Alignment constraints. size of Test is 8 instead of 5. NB: I changed member a from int to char type.

Your class layout is this:

```
class Test  size(8):
    +---
   0    | {vfptr}
   4    | a
        | <alignment member> (size=3)
    +---

  Test::$vftable@:
    | &Test_meta
    |  0
   0    | &Test::getA

  Test::getA this adjustor: 0
```